# Table rows as columns?

Tags: android, sqlite, pivot

I have the following two tables and the second one containts a **dynamic** amount of attributes for each entry of the first table:

```
people:

_id  |  name  |  first | status
----------------------------------
  1  |  Smtih |  Sam   |   on
  2  |   Doe  |  Joe   |   off


constraints: some people may have no more than in people, some may have 20:

_id  | persid |  type  | value
-------------------------------------------------
  1  |    2   |   IQ   |  90
  2  |    2   |  bold  |  yes
 ... |   ...  |   ...  |  ...
```

So as a intermediate result I would like to get this:

```
_id  |  name  |  first | status |  IQ  | bold | ...
------------------------------------------------  ... more depending on person
  2  |   Doe  |  Joe   |   off  |  90  |  yes | ...
```

so that I can eventually select those items with specific attributes e.g.:

`SELECT * FROM <--the above table--> WHERE status = 'off' AND IQ > '75'

I would be fine if those people who do not have the right attributes (in this case IQ) would not even show up in the intermediary table (quicker?).

Sadly, I did not get very far in my own feeble attempts. I guess `GROUP_CONCAT` should play a role, but can't get it to work.

As always, thank you guys in advance for your time and effort!

Comment: if you know all constraints types you should **generate query** like: `SELECT p._id AS _id, p.name AS name, p.first AS first, p.status AS status, iq.value AS IQ, bold.value AS bold, more1.value AS more1, ..., moreN.value AS moreN FROM people AS P LEFT OUTER JOIN constraints AS iq ON p._id = iq.persid and iq.type = 'iq' LEFT OUTER JOIN constraints AS bold ON p._id = bold.persid and bold.type = 'bold' LEFT OUTER JOIN constraints AS more1 ON p._id = more1.persid  and more1.type = 'more1'  ... LEFT OUTER JOIN constraints AS moreN ON p._id = moreN.persid  and moreN.type = 'moreN'`

Comment: No, I don't. The contraints can be entered manually.

Comment: you can always use: `SELECT DISTINCT type FROM constraints` to get list of types and then generate the query ... next problem is that value seems to be `TEXT` ... for strings:  `"7" > "75"` ...

Comment: Hmm, I really had hoped there'd be a solution using `GROUP_CONCAT` to simply transfor the rows to columns, like here: http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/qrytip.php?id=78  I will use the `LEFTER OUTER JOIN` solution (even though simply using `JOIN` seems to give the same result, so I'm not sure of the difference as of now). And indeed, the number/text problem is a whole different ballgame (maybe have two tables, one for text values and one for numerical values?)...

Answer (score 0):

As Selvin wrote, if you know all of the types, you can generate a query. But if you add the attributes by the time, you need two queries. The last part in the following code containing the `IQ` will not work, because `IQ` is not a column.

```
SELECT * FROM <--the above table--> WHERE status = 'off' AND IQ > '75'
```

First of all, you need to get the fixed information.

```
SELECT _id, name, first, status ...
```

There you can do your selection (for example by IQ):

```
SELECT _id, name, first, status FROM wherever WHERE (SELECT value FROM attributes WHERE persid = _id AND type='IQ') > 75
```

Finally, for each of the selected records you need to get the attributes.

```
SELECT value FROM attributes WHERE presid=_id_given_by_program
```